# Kendo ui grid on select

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, view, kendo-grid

I have a Driver table:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Dal.Driver>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("OrdersGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
          columns.Bound(o => o.FamilyName);
          columns.Bound(o => o.Licence);
          columns.Bound(o => o.ExperienceYears);
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.Id)))
      .Selectable(select => select.Enabled(true))
      .Events(e => e.Change())
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable()
      .Groupable()
    )
```

When client select a driver I want to add a multiply buttons that can navigate to other pages.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Below Code for enabling Grid Select. There are different modes like Multiple,Single and Types like Cells etc

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .Name("OrdersGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(200);
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Navigatable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
     )
);
```

Below code gives Select Event where you will get the detail of the selected column or row name along with the index

```
$(OrdersGrid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
var rowIdx = $("tr", OrdersGrid.tbody).index(row);
var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
var colName = $('#OrdersGrid').find('th').eq(colIdx).text()
alert("Selected cell on row: " + rowIdx + " and column name: " + colName);
});
```